# The native application freezes when starting

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-debug, android-anr-dialog

I'm developing an android app which is contains native part. I can not debug the native parts and it does not give any errors. After I wait for a while when I start the application, it gives the following warning but it's not crashing just freezing and waiting.

```
V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{5b69371 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a0f6556 {com.mcg.realtimeaudiosynthesis/com.mcg.realtimeaudiosynthesis.MainActivity}}
D/MessageLogger: >>> Entering MessageLogger.dump. to Dump MSG HISTORY <<<
D/MessageLogger: MSG HISTORY IN MAIN THREAD:
                 Current kernel time : 9189711ms
                 Last record : Msg#:4 >>>>> Dispatching to Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {377158fb} null: 100
                 Last record dispatching elapsedTime:8085 ms/upTime:8086 ms
                 Last record dispatching time : 2016-11-22 14:00:52.839
                 Msg#:3 <<<<< Finished to Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {377158fb} null elapsedTime:14 ms/upTime:14 ms
                 Msg#:2 >>>>> Dispatching to Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {377158fb} null: 110 from 2016-11-22 14:00:52.825
                 Msg#:1 <<<<< Finished to Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {377158fb} null elapsedTime:0 ms/upTime:1 ms
                 Msg#:0 >>>>> Dispatching to Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {377158fb} null: 138 from 2016-11-22 14:00:52.824
                 === Finish Dumping MSG HISTORY===
                 === LONGER MSG HISTORY IN MAIN THREAD ===
                 === Finish Dumping LONGER MSG HISTORY===
D/MessageQueue: Dump first 20 messages in Queue: 
D/MessageQueue: Dump Message in Queue (1): { when=-7s725ms what=149 obj=android.os.BinderProxy@a0f6556 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@a0f6556 }
D/MessageQueue: Total Message Count: 1
I/art: Thread[9,tid=4357,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb3906400,peer=0x12c40080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

On Debugger, debug disappears after a few steps but I'm still connected. Is there a way to trace native errors in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to trace native errors in detail?

For your particular case you can get a bit more information. Your app has got into **ANR** (Application Not Responding) state, and here:

```
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

you can find stack traces for all threads of your app at the moment when ANR conditions were detected by system. And maybe there are some other useful bits. This file should be accessible even without root privileges. Just run:

```
$ adb shell "cat /data/anr/traces.txt"
```